# Change SIM PIN on Android using reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I would like to change SIM card PIN number using java reflection. Final app will be installed in system/app.

The code I'm using is:

```
String ICCCARD_CLASS = "com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard";
String PHONEBASE_CLASS = "com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneBase";

Object phoneBaseObject = Class.forName(PHONEBASE_CLASS).getConstructor();
Object iccCardObject = Class.forName(ICCCARD_CLASS).newInstance(); 
Method iccCardMethod = Class.forName(ICCCARD_CLASS).getMethod("changeIccLockPassword", String.class, String.class, Message.class);

//Method arguments are...
Object arglist1[] = new Object[3];
arglist1[0] = "1111"; //oldPass
arglist1[1] = "2222"; //newPass
arglist1[2] = new Message(); //message handler (not needed)

iccCardMethod.invoke(iccCardObject, arglist1);
```

But, I'm getting a lot of exceptions like "no such method", "instantiation exception"...
In my Android project packages for IccCard and PhoneBase are not created.

TNX Hackers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that compiling indeed requires **android.jar** to be rebuilt with modified **classes.dex**.

Comment: I will post more links once I figure that out completely and check with 4.2.